# How to prevent duplicate entries Spring Jpa

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm learning how Spring framework works and as an example I'm trying to save cities and countries which users can log using the API endpoints. However, I can't figure out how to prevent duplicate entries.

For example I'm adding 2 cities in a country using the endpoint (**photo below**) but in the Country table I get duplicate values. How can I prevent duplicate values ? Thanks in advance.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRY")
public class CntCountry {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CntCountry", sequenceName = "CNT_COUNTRY_ID_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "CntCountry")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_NAME", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String countryName;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_CODE", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String countryCode;

}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "CITY")
@Entity
public class CtyCity {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CtyCity", sequenceName = "CTY_CITY_ID_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "CtyCity")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CITY_NAME", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String cityName;

    @Column(name = "PLATE_NUMBER", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private Long plateNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_COUNTRY")
    private CntCountry country;
}
```

[image: swaggerui]

[image: psql city]

[image: psql country]

EDIT:

```
@PostMapping("/city")
    public ResponseEntity<CtyCityDto> save(@RequestBody CtyCitySaveRequestDto ctyCitySaveRequestDto){
        CtyCityDto ctyCityDto = ctyCityService.save(ctyCitySaveRequestDto);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(ctyCityDto);
    }
```

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CtyCityService {
    private CtyCityDao ctyCityDao;

    public CtyCityDto save(CtyCitySaveRequestDto ctyCitySaveRequestDto){

        CtyCity ctyCity = CtyCityMapper.INSTANCE.convertToCtyCity(ctyCitySaveRequestDto);
        ctyCity = ctyCityDao.save(ctyCity);
        CtyCityDto ctyCityDto = CtyCityMapper.INSTANCE.convertToCtyCityDto(ctyCity);

        return ctyCityDto;
    }
}
```

```
public interface CtyCityDao extends JpaRepository<CtyCity,Long> {
}
```

```
@Data
public class CtyCityDto {
    private Long id;
    private String cityName;
    private Long plateNumber;
    private CntCountry country;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using to insert the data.

Comment: @tgdavies I added the code pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really following your naming conventions, and I think your DTO classes are just complicating things for you at this point... But in general terms, because the entities you're sending have no id value associated with them, JPA assumes they are different objects and adds them to the database with new id's because it hasn't been told anywhere that similar items might in fact be the same object, it needs to be told.

I can think of 2 ways to prevent entity duplication in your database.

**1.** The easiest way would be to set your Country and City names (or other attributes) to be "unique", you can do this in your entity classes simply by adding `unique = true` to the column data on the item you wish to be unique.

```java
//In Country.java
@Column(name = "COUNTRY_NAME", length = 30, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String countryName;

//In City.java
@Column(name = "CITY_NAME", length = 30, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String cityName;
```

Although, you will then need to handle exceptions thrown if a duplicate is provided, in Spring Boot the best way to handle this is with a `@ControllerAdvice` but that's another subject.

**2.** Check if the entity exists by name or some other value. A common approach might be something like the following:

```java
//In your service
public Object saveCountry(Country country){
    Country existingCountry = countryRepository.findByName(country.getName()).orElse(null);
    if(existingCountry == null){
        //Country does not already exist so save the new Country
        return countryRepository.save(country);
    }
    //The Country was found by name, so don't add a duplicate
    else return "A Country with that name already exists";
}


//In your Country repository
Optional<Country> findByName(countryName);
```

In case my answer doesn't make sense, I have thrown together an example following my first suggestion *(using the unique column attribute and a controller advice)* which you can [view/clone from here](https://github.com/AussieDev81/location-demo)

Comment: Also, if you use IntelliJ I suggest adding the [JPA Buddy](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15075-jpa-buddy) plugin if you don't already have it. They have a paid option, but they also provide their core features for free 

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed answer. Essentially you are right about the id issue. Because the id is not defined when I'm getting the city from the API endpoint, JPA indeed assumes them as new objects. So what I did was this: After I get the request body from the endpoint, I search the DB for the id and use setId() to set country id. After that I used `ctyCity = entityManager.merge(ctyCity);` and then save the city to DB. It works now.